# What is the correct code to reproduce the design of the following HTML element in vanillaframework?

Tags: html, css, card

I want to reproduce the following design of the [card component](https://vanillaframework.io/docs/patterns/card) in [Vanilla Framework](https://vanillaframework.io/). Please note, that only the **design** of the card element is of concern here and not the content inside the card element.

[image]

So far I have been able to reproduce this design.

[image: The design so far]

with the code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/vanilla-framework-version-4.2.0.min.css" />

<div class="col-4">
   <div class="p-card--highlighted">
      <img class="p-card__image" src="https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/0f33d832-The-State-of-Robotics.jpg">
      <div class="p-card__inner">
         <h3>The State of Robotics - August 2021</h3>
         <p>From robots learning to encourage social participation to detect serious environmental problems, it was a learning month.</p>
      </div>
      <hr class="u-no-margin--bottom">
      <div class="p-card__inner">
         by <a href="#">Bartek Szopka</a> on 21st August 2021
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Question: Since I want the design in the image 1

1. How do I bring the highlighted color at the top?
2. How do I round the edges of the card?
3. How do I deepen/darken the shadow of this card?

The framework I am using is [Vanilla Framework](https://vanillaframework.io/) and the component that I am using is [highlighted card](https://vanillaframework.io/docs/patterns/card#highlighted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How do I bring the highlighted color at the top?

You can use border-top in CSS.

For example:

```
<div style="border-top: 3px solid red"></div>
```

2. How do I round the edges of the card?

You can use border-radius in CSS.

For example:

```
<div style="border-radius: 10px"></div>
```

3. How do I deepen/darken the shadow of this card?

You can use box-shadow in CSS.

For example:

```
<div style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255)"></div>
```